# Why unicode() uses str() on my object only with no encoding given?

Tags: python, unicode, encoding

I start by creating a string variable with some **non-ascii** *utf-8* encoded data on it:

```
>>> text = 'á'
>>> text
'\xc3\xa1'
>>> text.decode('utf-8')
u'\xe1'
```

Using `unicode()` on it raises errors...

```
>>> unicode(text)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 0: 
                    ordinal not in range(128)
```

...but if I know the encoding I can use it as second parameter:

```
>>> unicode(text, 'utf-8')
u'\xe1'
>>> unicode(text, 'utf-8') == text.decode('utf-8')
True
```

Now if I have a class that returns this text in the `__str__()` method:

```
>>> class ReturnsEncoded(object):
...     def __str__(self):
...         return text
... 
>>> r = ReturnsEncoded()
>>> str(r)
'\xc3\xa1'
```

`unicode(r)` seems to use `str()` on it, since it raises the same error as `unicode(text)` above:

```
>>> unicode(r)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 0: 
                    ordinal not in range(128)
```

Until now everything is as planned!

**But as no one would ever expect, `unicode(r, 'utf-8')` won't even try:**

```
>>> unicode(r, 'utf-8')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, ReturnsEncoded found
```

Why? Why this inconsistent behavior? Is it a bug? is it intended? Very awkward.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The behaviour does seem confusing, but intensional. I reproduce here the entirety of the unicode documentation from the [Python Built-In Functions documentation](http://docs.python.org/lib/built-in-funcs.html) (for version 2.5.2, as I write this):

> **unicode([object[, encoding [, errors]]])**
>
> Return the Unicode string version of object using one of the following modes:
>
> If encoding and/or errors are given, unicode() will decode the
>      object which can either be an 8-bit string or a character buffer
>      using the codec for encoding. The encoding parameter is a string
>      giving the name of an encoding; if the encoding is not known,
>      LookupError is raised. Error handling is done according to
>      errors; this specifies the treatment of characters which are
>      invalid in the input encoding. If errors is 'strict' (the
>      default), a ValueError is raised on errors, while a value of
>      'ignore' causes errors to be silently ignored, and a value of
>      'replace' causes the official Unicode replacement character,
>      U+FFFD, to be used to replace input characters which cannot be
>      decoded. See also the [codecs](http://docs.python.org/lib/module-codecs.html) module.
>
> If no optional parameters are given, unicode() will mimic the
>      behaviour of str() except that it returns Unicode strings
>      instead of 8-bit strings. More precisely, if object is a Unicode
>      string or subclass it will return that Unicode string without
>      any additional decoding applied.
>
> For objects which provide a __unicode__() method, it will call
>      this method without arguments to create a Unicode string. For
>      all other objects, the 8-bit string version or representation is
>      requested and then converted to a Unicode string using the codec
>      for the default encoding in 'strict' mode.
>
> New in version 2.0. Changed in version 2.2: Support for __unicode__() added.

So, when you call `unicode(r, 'utf-8')`, it requires an 8-bit string or a character buffer as the first argument, so it coerces your object using the `__str__()` method, and attempts to decode that using the `utf-8` codec. Without the `utf-8`, the `unicode()` function looks for a for a `__unicode__()` method on your object, and not finding it, calls the `__str__()` method, as you suggested, attempting to use the default codec to convert to unicode.

Answer (score 5):

`unicode` does not guess the encoding of your text. If your object can print itself as `unicode`, define the `__unicode__()` method that returns a Unicode string.

---

The secret is that `unicode(r)` is not actually calling `__str__()` itself. Instead, it's looking for a `__unicode__()` method. The default implementation of `__unicode__()` will call `__str__()` and then attempt to decode it using the `ascii` charset. When you pass the encoding, `unicode()` expects the first object to be something that can be decoded -- that is, an instance of `basestring`.

---

> Behavior is weird because it tries to decode as ascii if I don't pass 'utf-8'. But if I pass 'utf-8' it gives a different error...

That's because when you specify "utf-8", it treats the first parameter as a string-like object to be decoded. Without it, it treats the parameter as an object to be coerced to unicode.

I do not understand the confusion. If you know that the object's `text` attribute will always be UTF-8 encoded, just define `__unicode__()` and then everything will work fine.

Comment: I think I may not have made myself clear. I know that. What I mean is to know WHY unicode(r) has a different behavior than unicode(r, 'utf-8')???

Comment: Behavior is weird because it tries to decode as ascii if I don't pass 'utf-8'. But if I pass 'utf-8' it gives a different error...